# relative paths in python not finding parent package

Tags: python

I have a file system like this at the moment.

```
app
 |--__init__.py (empty)
 |    
 |--domain
 |    |--__init__.py (empty)
 |    |--model.py
 |    |--questionmatcher.py
 |
 |--interface
 |    |--__init__.py (empty)
 |    |--basiccli.py
 |    |--userinterface.py
 |
 |--parser
 |    |--__init__.py (empty)
 |    |--json_loader.py
 |    |--parsing.py
 |
 |--testfiles
 |    |--__init__.py (empty)
 |    |--testsuite.py
```

I am trying to run the testsuite.py which will need to import classes from various files in directory.

I have tried this structure:

```py
import unittest
from ..parser.json_loader import JsonLoader
from ..parser.parsing import get_vectors, parseThreadsFromFile, getPostsFromThreads
from ..domain import UniversalEncoder, SentBERT

class TestParsing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        pass


class TestJson(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        pass


class TestModelEncoders(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        pass



if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.main()
```

However when I go to run the test I get:

```
    from ..parser.json_loader import JsonLoader
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried

```py
from parser.json_loader import JsonLoader
```

but now I get

```
    from parser.json_loader import JsonLoader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parser.json_loader'; 'parser' is not a package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks, but that hasn't fixed it. I tried removing the relative imports but it gives me ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parser.json_loader'; 'parser' is not a package``.

Comment: What command are you typing to run the `testsuite.py` script?

Comment: @mkreiger1 ``python app/testfiles/testsuite.py``

Comment: also tried changing directory to ``testfiles`` and just running ``python testsuite.py``

Comment: You need to import `app.parser.json_loader`, not `parser.json_loader`.

Comment: No, running the script from outside the package is correct.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Tried that and got ``from app.parser.json_loader import JsonLoader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'``

Comment: I think you should run `python3 -m app.testfiles.testsuite` while in the parent directory of `app`. I'm not sure if the `python` comand uses Python 3 in your case.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have made python default to using python 3, so ``python3 ..`` does not work for me

Comment: OK then `python -m app.testfiles.testsuite`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks! that did the trick. However, why is it ``python -m app.testfiles.testsuite`` and not ``python app\testfiles\testsuite.py``?

Comment: I can't really explain it now. It should be explained in the answers to the other question I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this package to your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/parser
```

Comment: I'd rather not go adding things like that. It shouldn't be this hard to import packages. But it seems like reading a view of the other similar stackoverflow questions, people are having big troubles with understanding relative imports